# Does the set of bounded real sequence is finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Does the set of bounded real sequence is finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

I thinks yes bounded implies finite ....so it will be finite dimensional vector space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not finite dimensional. Let $x(n)$ be the sequence whose $n$<sup>th</sup> term is $1$ and all other terms are $0$. Then each $x(n)$ belongs to your space and $\{x(n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is an infinite linearly independent set.